# Set Zoom Level of Map to particular Zip Code

Tags: mapquest

I am using MapQuest JS batch API to plot multiple address on the map. I am able to pass multiple address & plot pins accordingly. I following example on below link. The map may have multiple pins plotted all over USA, I want to set the zoom level of the map, conditionally to particular zip code.

https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/samples/geocoding/v1/batch/

Currently the zoom level is set to best Fit

```
var options = {
        elt: "map",
        zoom: 10,
        mtype: 'map'
      };

var map = new MQA.TileMap(options);
map.bestFit();
```

I am expecting to set zoom level to specific zip code based on certain criteria.

Updates: 01/20
On the below link, there is a option to set initial center of the map to particular latitude/longitude. but this did not work for me

https://developer.mapquest.com/docs/api-reference/javascript-api/classes/MQA.TileMap.html

Option:
[latLng] MQA.LatLng optional 
the initial map center as a MQA.LatLng Default: {lat: 38.134557, lng: -98.4375}

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, both the map center and zip code questions have been addressed in the MapQuest developer forum [post](https://developer.mapquest.com/forum/how-set-zoom-level-particular-zip-code).

https://developer.mapquest.com/forum/how-set-zoom-level-particular-zip-code

Comment: I got it working using the latlng option with the zoom level set to 5.